# C String Reversed

Tags: c, string

I am writing a simple c program which reverses a string, taking the string from argv[1]. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* flip_string(char *string){
    int i = strlen(string);
    int j = 0;

    // Doesn't really matter all I wanted was the same size string for temp.
    char* temp = string;
    puts("This is the original string");
    puts(string);
    puts("This is the \"temp\" string");
    puts(temp);

    for(i; i>=0; i--){
        temp[j] = string[i]
        if (j <= strlen(string)) {
            j++;
        }
    }

    return(temp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    puts(flip_string(argv[1]));
    printf("This is the end of the program\n");
}
```

That's basically it, the program compiles and everything but does not return the temp string in the end (just blank space). In the beginning it prints temp fine when its equal to string. Furthermore if I do a character by character printf of temp in the for loop the correct temp string in printed i.e. string -> reversed. Just when I try to print it to standard out (after the for loop/ or in the main) nothing happens only blank space is printed.

thanks

Comment: I wrote this in the Ubuntu forums as well, but figured it is more of a general coding question.

Comment: You know that `temp` and `string` point to the very same memory location?

Comment: Don't forget to accept WhozCraig answer, it's the right way to do what you want. Nice and clean.

Comment: Minor nit: Don't call strlen() over and over on a string that isn't varying in length inside a loop.  Call it once and store the result.  Then use the stored value inside the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were going in the correct direction trying to use a pointer. Just a little more thought and you probably would have had it. A safe implementation appears below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *flip_string(char *str)
{
    char *lhs = str, *rhs = str;
    if (!str || !*str || !*(str+1))
        return str;

    while (*++rhs); // rhs to eos
    while (lhs < --rhs)
    {
        char tmp = *lhs;
        *lhs++ = *rhs;
        *rhs = tmp;
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char test1[] = "Hello, World!";
    char test2[] = "";
    char test3[] = "1";
    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", flip_string(test1), flip_string(test2), flip_string(test3));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
!dlroW ,olleH, , 1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the important difference between `char[]` and `char*`.  In this context, it copies the string, otherwise it would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think it's irritating to have `flip_string` do an in-place reversal *and* return the argument. Somebody who looks at the `printf` line probably wouldn't expect that `flip_string` actually *modifies* its argument as well. Implementing this idea means you no longer need to keep the original `str` pointer, so you could just as well use it for traversal, saving one local variable.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I agree. For whatever reason it was what was the apparent requirement. Were it not for that I would have done as you described; just march up the ranks with `str`. And of course, all of this is utter-fail with mb-chars such as, and certainly not limited to, utf8.

Answer (score 3):

Your function appears to do an 'in-place reversal', i.e. it replaces the given string in memory. When doing so, make sure that you *do not* move the trailing zero to the front. Here's a simple implementation of the function

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

void flip_string(char *s)
{
    assert(s);
    char *t = strchr(s, '\0') - 1;
    for (; s < t; ++s, --t) {
        char tmp = *s;
        *s = *t;
        *t = tmp;
    }
}
```

The function asserts that it gets a string (i.e. not a null pointer) and that the memory is writable. It then sets up a `t` pointer to point to the last character of the string - doing this via `strchr` instead of writing a manual loop has the benefit that `strchr` is usually a highly optimized function which doesn't traverse the string in single-byte steps but rather considers four or even more bytes at a time. It's also arguably more expressive.

The main loop then swaps the characters referenced by `s` and `t` (i.e. initially the first and the last character) and then moves the pointers forwards/backwards until they meet.

The function is a bit more concise because it doesn't need to retain the original pointer passed in, instead it can modify `s` directly. This is a result of deciding that a function should *either* modify its argument *or* return a new value - but not both. Doing both means you could call the function like

```
printf("%s", flip_string(s));
```

...and this would totally obscure that `s` is actually modified.

```
flip_string(s);
printf("%s", s);
```

is more explicit in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you obviously want `temp` to be an other variable than `string`. But the initialization you made will result in the two pointers pointing to the same location.

What you should do instead is :

```
char *flip_string(const char *string)
{
    char *tmp = NULL;
    size_t len = strlen(string);
    int i = 0;
    /*
     * Don't forget that strlen() returns the length of the string
     * **WITHOUT** counting the ending '\0' character.
     * Thus, you have to add the extra space when you're allocating
     */
    if (!(tmp = malloc(len + 1))) {
        printf("Allocation failed ...\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    /*
     * The newly created string must have an ending character
     * Which is '\0'
     */

    tmp[len] = '\0';

    /*
     * Here, you want to reverse the "true content" of your string.
     * That is why you ignore the ending '\0' of the string by
     * setting the upper bound to strlen (with a strict '<') **AND**
     * it is also the reason a '- 1' just pops in the index choice.
     */
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        tmp[i] = string[len - i - 1];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

As underlined by WhozCraig, there is an alternative solution which simply modifies the argument string without requiring memory allocation :

```
void flip_string(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *p = s + len - 1;
    while (s < p) {
        *p ^= *s;
        *s ^= *p;
        *p ^= *s;
        p--;
        s++;
    }
}
```

Note the `XOR` trick to avoid using a temporary storage variable for the swapped character (`^` is the `XOR` operator in **C**)

Comment: You may, but I don't. There is no reason to allocate memory *at all* to reverse a standard zero-terminated string. Two pointers and a  while-loop (two if you want independence from `strlen()`) is all that is needed.

Comment: @WhozCraig, you should post it, your answer should be much more instructive than mine (there is no irony here !).

Comment: Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1. (and that's a weird syntax for a NULL-check...) Apart from that, I don't like the XOR swap.

Comment: The second version is buggy and uses the XOR trick, which is not necessary here.

Comment: @anatolyg, understood the misbehavior and fixed it :)

Comment: @H2CO3, I usually do my `NULL` checks depending on the context (if I am working on code that checks NULL pointers using `!` or other that uses `NULL`). I added the `XOR` swap because even though it is quite useless, it might be interesting to know it. Could you give me a pragmatic reason of your dislike so I can make my answer better by quoting this reason

Comment: @rerito The XOR trick is not obvious. The more readable naive approach that involves a temporary variable is, so you can know at first glance what is happening. Also, assignment is more general than arithmetic, in the sense that the XOR swap wouldn't work with floating-point numbers or structs.